# Understanding different formats of coordinates

Tags: sql, sqlite, gps, coordinates, gis

I'm trying to understand a latitude/longitude format, that has been converted somehow.

In SQL database:

Lat: -291408339

Lon: -303920096

Address: River Fire Line, Lower Glenelg National Park

When I check it by address in Google Maps, I get

Lat: -38.01569

Lon: 141.34876

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE sites ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(150), address VARCHAR(250), phone VARCHAR(40), website VARCHAR(250), state INTEGER, lat INTEGER, lng INTEGER, type INTEGER, facility INTEGER, flags INTEGER, extras INTEGER, date INTEGER, score INTEGER, ratings INTEGER, previous INTEGER, hidden INTEGER )
```

Snapshot:
[image: Database]

How to convert them?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column data type?

Comment: I'm viewing them with sqlitebrowser and column type is INTEGER

Comment: *"How to convert them?"* Looks like you try to convert apples to pears the numbers are not the same here..

Comment: In which SR you have saved  the values i coordinates .. ???  the first seems metric coord and the second wgs84 .. for a proper conversion we need  the System Reference for the first coordinates

Comment: I edited question and added more info

Comment: This is almost certainly a map projection. I've tried a few common Australian ones at [https://epsg.io/](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3112&x=141.3487600&y=-38.0156900) but none seem to match. However there is a push to use some new datum (GDA 2020), but none of the transformations currently work on epsg.io so I can't tell if that's correct. Is it possible to go back to your source and ask? Otherwise it's mostly guess work; and it's even possible that different systems are used in different parts of Australia, but all mushed obscurely together in your database.